# Merging two data frames with common column doesn't work

Tags: pandas, merge

I really don't know why this doesn't work but i have the following:

DF:(these has 1896 rows × 2 columns)

| EntityId | EntityName |
| --- | --- |
| 12495813 | ABC ltd |
| 53653525 | CDE ltd |

DF1: (6 ROWS )

| EntityId | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 12495813 | 13 |
| 12495813 | 213 |

I want my output to merge the EntityName in DF1.

I have tried this `merged_Frame = pd.merge(df, df1, on = 'EntityId')` but it came blank, i made sure df contains the entity id in df1 so i am not sure what i am doing wrong. Thanks a lot!